# Mod_rewrite: grab second URL string in regular expression

Tags: regex, apache, url, mod-rewrite

The site I am working on changes URLs with rules like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ string.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]
```

thus producing id/slug. I want to remove the ID part, but do not know how to select only the slug. Doing:

```
(.*)/$ string.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]
```

creates a URL from the ID and not the slug...

This is probably a simple answer, but I cannot find it... thanks!

Comment: Wait, so you want to remove the id entirely and only rely on the slug like `example.com/slug`? Or you don't want the id in the final query string like `example.com/id/slug >> string.php?slug=slug` ??

Comment: What should your final URL look like and what should it direct to?

Comment: sorry, I want example.com/slug. Thanks!

Comment: I just found a typo in my code below. Edited...

Answer (score 0):

To match only the slug, you want to capture the slug into `$1`. Your attempt captured a `$1`, but passed it into `id=`.

```
# [^/]+ matches everything up to but not including /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ string.php?slug=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I wrote `RewriteRule ^([^/])+$ contactus.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]` but it crashed the website... Firefox said the site was using redirects in a way that would never complete.

Comment: I somewhat blindly tried adding a slash before the $ - `RewriteRule ^([^/])+/$ contactus.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]` which stopped the crashing, but does not work as a redirect.

Comment: `# [^/]+ matches everything up to but not including /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/])+$ contactus.php?slug=$1 [L,NC]`

did not crash, but the new URLs did not work. I tried too adding the id string to the query:

`# [^/]+ matches everything up to but not including /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/])+$ contactus.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]`

with the same results. Thanks though for your efforts to help me so far :)

Comment: @JuanPonderas If your script expects the presence of the id, you must pass it in the URL. If not, omit it.  To debug, add `[L,NC,R=301]` to see where it is actually redirecting to since it will redirect the browser rather than rewrite internally

Comment: Fixed the typo, but the redirect still does not work :/ the scripts of the site require the id- I just want it to not be in the URL sent to users. More of my code, if helpful:

`Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

# Force WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

...

RewriteRule ^contact/$ contact.php [L,NC]

...
# [^/]+ matches everything up to but not including /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ contactus.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]

`

Comment: @JuanPonderas If the scripts need the id, unless you are looking up the id via the slug, it _must_ be in the URL the users use. You cannot rewrite the browser's URL to remove the id without also redirecting the page. If they don't have the id, how is the server supposed to get the id?

Comment: The following code changes the URL correctly to browsers while sending the ID to the server, which can use it:

`RewriteRule ^san-francisco/$ contactus.php?id=1&slug=san-francisco [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^new-york/$ contactus.php?id=2&slug=new-york [L,NC]
`

That works here because I have two locations, which do not change, but other categories have hundreds of ever-changing pages, so I want to abstract from this code...

Comment: The code `
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ contactus.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]` resulted pages that worked and had the URLs with the ID but not the slug, like website.com/1/. Would it not be possible to thus get the slug rather than the id there?

Comment: @JuanPonderas That's what my rule above does - it doesn't include `id=`. But if your PHP script cannot handle an empty id value, then it cannot route to the correct document.

Comment: The goal is to use the `id` for the server but not end-user URLs, and that seems possible given that code like `RewriteRule ^san-francisco/$ contactus.php?id=1&slug=san-francisco [L,NC]` works... and having automatically created URLs with one slug but not the other also works. Is there some reason those two features could not be combined?

Comment: @JuanPonderas That URL includes `id=1`. The id is hard-coded in the rewrite rule.  Unless you hard-code all of them, Apache has no way itself of matching a slug to an id. That routing logic is the job of the application code. If you application can lookup a slug to match to an id, great, use that.

Comment: But `RewriteRule ^san-francisco/$ contactus.php?id=1&slug=san-francisco [L,NC]` does not include an `id=1` in the URL!

To put it this way, say I wanted to reverse the order of the slug and the ID- www.website.com/slug/id for example. Would it be possible to write a pattern that would do that? If so, I would think I could then just drop the ID part... (thanks again for your help, btw :)

Comment: @JuanPonderas Yes you could reverse them, but it still does not guarantee that your application can use the slug if the id isn't present.  `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ contactus.php?slug=$1&id=$2 [L,NC]`

Comment: Intriguing. That resulted in all pages of the site being displayed without CSS or images. I tried too `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.*)$ contactus.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L,NC]` but no dice...

Comment: @JuanPonderas You still need the two `RewriteCond`

Comment: I think I see your point- the code uses the ID to match the URL to the page in the database. I would have to then rewrite the PHP to have the slug do that, which might be involved. Well. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem was that you were using slug=$2, but your updated RewriteRule didn't have a second capture group.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ string.php?slug=$1 [L,NC]
```

If your URL is http://www.example.com/slug this will produce http://www.example.com/string.php?slug=slug

Comment: Does not work :/ I'm curious how that is intended to work. It would seem to me that the new URL would have two parts and substitution path would go to somewhere that does not exist, though my understanding of this is not too comprehensive...

Comment: I've updated my answer, I was confused on what you were trying to match, and also what you wanted to be produced.